# Share controller between two directives with sibling relationship

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there an option to "use, share, inherit" the scope of a directive-controller by another directive? 
It's important that there isn't a parent-child relationsship, instead of they are siblings. With the following code, I get the error message that the controller "creditableSumB" isn't found:

```
timeTrackingModule.directive("creditableSum", function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        require: '^^creditableSumB',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            console.log(scope);
        },
        template: '<div>' +
                        'LOL' +
                  '</div>'
    }
})

timeTrackingModule.directive("creditableSumB", function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'EAC',
        controllerAs: 'creditableSumB',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            console.log(scope);
        },
        template: '<div>' +
                        'LOL' +
                  '</div>'
    }
})
```

Comment: You have a few options depending on what you're trying to do: create a parent controller under which both directives exist, use a value, or use a service.

Comment: Post your full code including your html and controllers..in order to give correct answer

Comment: @Lex Yep, I know your solution with one parent controller is the appropriate way, but I must not modify the way the directive I want to access it's scope.